# Using JS to cancel an In Progress Download from a node.js server

Tags: javascript, download, cancel-button

I have a node.js web server that sends large file downloads (<2GB) in a response to a client. I have a cancel button in the client but I need for it to be able to cancel downloads that have already started (already in the browser download tray).  Currently, the cancel button only stops the page which stops new downloads.

This post is the closest I've come to finding a similar problem: [Cancel long running download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869935/cancel-long-running-download).

Thanks for any help!